# AWS Glacier multipart uploads: last part size --range options

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I want to upload 12.8G file using AWS Glacier Multipart upload command.
So divide the file into 2GB.(6 files x 2GB, 1 file x 800MB)

```
aws glacier init-multipart-upload --account-id - --valut-name vaultname_xxx --part-size 2147483648
```

```
aws glacier upload-multipart-part --account-id - --vault-name vaultname_xxx --upload-id uploadid_xxxxxx --body /upload/file1 --range 'bytes 0-2147483647/*'
```

enter command while changing the file name and the number of bytes.

btw, what is '--range' option value for last 800MB file??

and what is checksum options value when complete-multipart-upload command